# asp.net formview data tool

Tags: asp.net

the formview in data tools in asp.net by default gives textbox in insert mode template.
how to change this  to textarea or dropdown selection list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edit the EditItemTemplate in the ASPX page.

See [this article](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-the-formview-s-templates-cs)